# Can the function length() take arguments?

Tags: c++, string, string-length

I have experimented with the string `length()` function to see what can parameters it can take and I get the following error:
Q8.cxx:88:17: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1

Does this mean this function can never take any arguments? I am curious because it has brackets, `()`. I want to know if there are some functions in c++ that never take any arguments, but they still have brackets.

Comment: ***I want to know if there are some functions in c++ that never take any arguments, but they still have brackets.*** Without the brackets you don't have a function call. You have a pointer instead. So even though a function has no arguments you can not omit the () and still call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Can the function length() take arguments?" - No.

If you [look it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), you'll see that `std::string::length()` takes *no arguments*. So of course you cannot call it with any.

The brackets `()` simply mean "call a function". Any arguments go within the brackets. Empty brackets means "call the function with no arguments".

The name of the function *without* the brackets means something completely different. It means "pointer to the function", *not* function *call*.

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses (brackets) mark a **function call**. Function calls **always** have parentheses. `length()` calls the function whose name is `length` and passes no arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of the language determines that any function can be called by using brackets `()`, regardless if it expected to receive any arguments.